# place div in middle of div with 100 percent image in bg

Tags: html, css

I want to have a div that contains an image that will fit to 100%

plus

another button that will be set to the middle and on top of the image in the middle, vertical and horizontal.

strangely the button is always behind the image...

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/78xdJ/

HTML:

```
<div id="holder">
    <img src="http://mannerofspeaking.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/black1.gif" />
    <input type="button" value="aaaa" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#holder{
    position: relative;
}
#holder img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
#holder input{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To fit the img perfectly as background:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: how can I make this div to be full even if not content in it? full I mean that the bg image will be seen fully

Comment: By specifying his height and width. That is not good for responsive design !

Answer (score 1):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/mouhammed/78xdJ/4/

HTML :

```
<div id="holder">
    <img src="http://mannerofspeaking.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/black1.gif" />
    <input type="button" value="aaaa" />
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#holder{
    position: relative;
}

#holder img{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}

#holder input{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    display: block;
    margin-left:-44px; /* negative margin with the width of button*/
    margin-top:-21px; /* negative margin with the height of button*/
    z-index:100;

}
```

Comment: I don't want to place the button with absolute and than margin minus, because the content in the button is dynamic, so the button wouldn't be in the middle if the text is a bit long

Comment: Does the image will always have the same resolution ?

Comment: If you make the image as background, you must specify the #holder div height and width to make image appear. The only way to show button on top of image is by using absolute.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated @mouhammed's answer a bit to put the button in the center no matter what.

http://jsfiddle.net/9FxeC/1/

Essentially, you use

```
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

to pull the button element back towards the top/left by half of its width/height.

This should work in all modern browsers and back to ie9.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, I place the image with absolute and add div container for the button that it is absolute as well.

```
<style>
#holder{
position: relative;
}
#holder img{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
#holder div{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
text-align: center;
}
</style>

<div id="holder">
    <img src="http://mannerofspeaking.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/black1.gif" />
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="aaaa" />
    </div>
</div>
```